# How to hide HUD in Titan Quest Anniversary Edition?

Tags: titan-quest, titan-quest-anniversary-edition

The HUD obstructs my screenshots. Is there a hotkey or other way to hide the HUD?

[image]

Comment: Is this different in the ANniversary edition than in the old version? Or is this a general "Can I hide the HUD in Titan Quest?" question? I'm assuming the second and removing the titan-quest-ae tag. Since I'm pretty sure there is no difference (I do not know the answer though)

Comment: @Arperum: I added Anniversary Edition tag to make clear what version I'm playing. Here's patchlog for AE: http://titanquestgame.com/pcchangelog/TQ_AnniversaryEdition_FullChangelog.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anniversary Edition, got every download for now, except Eternal Embers.

The Keybinding menu has "Toggle UI" as the second to last Function, and I haven't changed my settings, so I assume the Default is F8. Which does as it seems, it turns off the HUD / UI.

Tested it just now.